# Convergence of a sequence whose even and odd subsequences converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that the subsequences $\{a_{2n−1}\}$ and $\{a_{2n}\}$ converge to the same limit, say $a$. Show that $\{a_n\}$ also converges to $a$.

Comment: I tried with epsilone definition but don't know how to proceed

Comment: What did the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition tell you about the subsequences?

Comment: Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. There is an $N_1$ such that if $n\gt N_1$ then $|a_{2n-1}-a|\lt \epsilon$. There is an $N_2$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: I would use an argument involving a M= max{$N_1, N_2$}, where $N_1$ is the "N" necessary for {$a_{2n-1}$} to converge, and $N_2$ is the "N" necessary for {$a_{2n}$} to converge. Then any epsilon neighbourhood contains all points in the main sequence whose index is greater than M.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: Take any $\epsilon>0.$ Since $a_{2n-1}\to a,$ then there is an $N_1$ such that $|a_{2n-1}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_1.$ Likewise, there is an $N_2$ such that $|a_{2n}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_2.$ How can we use $N_1$ and $N_2$ to come up with an $N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$?

Comment: Is N=max(2$N_1$-1,  2$N_2$) ??

Comment: Yes, indeed! That does exactly what we need it to.

Comment: Why wouldn't N=max(N_1,N_2) do the job? (why the need for the multiplication with 2?)

Comment: @Wouter: For a simple example, consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ given by $$a_n:=\begin{cases}n & \text{if }n\text{ is even and }n<10\\0 & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ which clearly converges to $0,$ since it starts like $0,2,0,4,0,6,0,8,$ and then is $0$ forever after. Then $|a_{2n-1}-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_1:=1,$ regardless of our choice of $\epsilon>0.$ Take any $\epsilon\in(0,2).$ Then $|a_{2n}-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_2:=4.$ However, it is *not* the case that $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>\max(N_1,N_2)=4.$ Do you see why? Does that clear things up?

Comment: @CameronBuie I see why my N wouldn't hold. Thank you. The only question is how i intuitively would have known beforehand to multiply it with 2 (without thinking of a counterexample).

Comment: @Wouter: It's really just a matter of carefully paying attention to what $N_1$ and $N_2$ actually tell us. We need $n$ to be bigger than the biggest odd index that might fail--that is, bigger than $2N_1-1$--and also bigger than the biggest even index that might fail--that is, bigger than $2N_2.$ Does that make sense when put in those terms?

Comment: @CameronBuie after your comment and thinking it over a lot, i think it makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: @Wouter: You're welcome!

Comment: Cameron, that was a very good example :)