# A question on upper and lower derivatives of $F$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, limsup-and-liminf

This question is from the book The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock.

[image]

I'm currently reading part of the book
**The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock.**
Slight confusion arise on the following definition of upper and lower derivative.

Im kinda stuck on understanding why
$$\overline{D} F(x) = \max \{D^+F(x), D^-F(x)\},$$

On my a perspective, for $\delta>0$, $x<y<x+\delta$ and $x-\delta<y<x$, implies
$$0<|x-y|<\delta.$$

The following link
[$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup x_n= \max(x,y)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf x_n= \min(x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267131/lim-n-to-infty-sup-x-n-maxx-y-and-lim-n-to-infty-inf-x-n-minx-y/1267446#1267446)

Makes up the same conclusion, but sequence taken is not of the form as supremum in this case runs over $y$ with $x<y<x+\delta$.

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing is merging two one-sided $\limsup$s into one two-sided one.

Throwing out all the symbols en masse:
$$\begin{align*}\overline{D}F(x)&=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\sup_{0<|y-x|<\delta}\frac{F(y)-F(x)}{y-x}\\
&=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\sup_{\substack{0<y-x<\delta\\\text{or}\\0<x-y<\delta}}(...)\\
&=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\max\left(\sup_{x<y<x+\delta}(...),\sup_{x-\delta<y<x}(...)\right)\\
&=\max\left(\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\sup_{x<y<x+\delta}(...), \lim_{\delta\rightarrow0^+}\sup_{x-\delta<y<x}(...)\right)\\
&=\max(D^+F(x),D^-F(x))
\end{align*}$$
where of course, you switch the $\lim$ and $\max$ by requiring everything be defined.